# Change colors for lines, when passing a matrix as output variable in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an `x` vector of size `n`, and an `(n,p)` `mu` matrix. When I place it in pyplot, I get:

```
plt.plot(x_train_inv, y_train_inv, 'go', alpha=0.5, markerfacecolor='none')
plt.plot(x, mu)
```

[image]

The green line is a not seen very well with the green dots, and I would like to change it's color. Is it possible in this set up? (where the "y" is a matrix) If so - how?

**EDIT** - a reproducible example:

```
x  = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = np.c_[x**2, np.cos(x), np.exp(x)]
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

I wish to pass something to the last line to specify the color per column in y, e.g.: `plt.plot(x, y, color)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set_color`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_color).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

COLORS = ['#ff5555', '#00ffaa', '#9900ff']

x  = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = np.c_[x**2, np.cos(x), np.exp(x)]

line = plt.plot(x, y)
for idx, color in enumerate(COLORS):
    line[idx].set_color(color)
plt.show()
```

[image: matrix_lines]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy

x  = numpy.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = x**2
mu = numpy.random.normal(0,1, 200)
mu = mu.reshape((len(x), 2))
# plt.plot(x_train_inv, y_train_inv, 'go', alpha=0.5, markerfacecolor='none')
plt.plot(x, mu, 'go')
plt.plot(x, y, "r--")
```

Comment: This is not what I asked. I ask to pass some vector/matrix to the `plt.plot(x, mu)` to specify the colors per column... e.g., `plt.plot(x, mu, colors)`